# How to configure SSL/ HTTPS in JBoss 7.0 EAP Server?

Tags: java, xml, https, server, jboss

I have seen a lot of sites showing the ssl configuration by editing `standalone.xml` file and adding the following tag inside the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" native="false" default-virtual-server="default-host">` tag.

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enabled="true" secure="true"/>
```

This works fine with JBoss 6.4 server. However,  Jboss 7.0 does not contain the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1"` tag. When I tried to write that tag on my own it showed an invocation error while starting the server.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss EAP 7 server, you need to make changes under "undertow" subsystem, for example:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
             <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
                 <https-listener name="https" secure="true" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" security-realm="CertificateRealm" socket-binding="https"/>`
            ...
```